# Hunspell python detects words as english only if first letter is capitalised

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, hunspell

For example "India" is detected as true but "india" is false

```
d = Hunspell()
d.spell('india')
Out[59]: False

d.spell('India')
Out[60]: True
```

How do i get hunspell to detect both as true

Comment: I want to check if a variable X is english word or not. I dont want to capitalise the first character of X everytime

Comment: The word "India" *must* be capitalised, just like "England". They are [proper nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun).

Comment: I understand, but i have no control over the variable X i am going to be entering into hunspell